# Is there a way to fix "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'user_score' referenced before assignment"?

Tags: python

I'm fairly new at coding and I'm making a game in which the user plays a random card drawing game against the computer. The goal is to reach 50 points first and you reach that by drawing the cards. For example, a 2 of Clubs should have a value of 2 and a King of Hearts should have a value of 13. However, as I was editing my code, it randomly showed an error that I'm not familiar with, nor know how to fix. Can anyone help me? I've tried to fix it by adding in "global user_score, random_drawn_card, computer_score" in the game_type function, which brought another error message saying "SyntaxError: name 'user_score' is used prior to global declaration". Can anyone help me?

## This is a minimal version of my code so you can disregard everything between "class Card" to "sorted_deck = [Card(n, s) for s in Card.suits for n in range(1, 14)]"

```
# Useful Definitions
user_score = 0
computer_score = 0
user_turn_score = 0
computer_turn_score = 0
type = "user"
winner = "none"
import random



class Card:
    suits = {'c': '♣','h': '♥','s': '♠','d': '♦'}
    faces = {
        1: 'Ace',
        11: 'Jack',
        12: 'Queen',
        13: 'King'
    }
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        '''Called when you create a new card. For example `Card(10, 'h')`'''
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
    
    def __repr__(self):
        '''A string representation of the card'''
        face = self.faces.get(self.rank, self.rank)
        return f'{face}{self.suits[self.suit]}'
        
    def __add__(self, other):
        '''What happens when you add a card to another (or to an integer)
           For example this_card + someOther_card'''
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return self.rank + other
        return self.rank + other.rank

    def __radd__(self, other):
        '''What happens when you add another or integer to this card. 
           For example `someOther_card + this_card`'''
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return other + self.rank
        return self.rank + other.rank
        
sorted_deck = [Card(n, s) for s in Card.suits for n in range(1, 14)]




def game_turn(type):
    
    while user_score != 50 and computer_score != 50:
        global user_score, random_drawn_card, computer_score
        if type == "user":
            cont = input("It is your turn, " + user_name + ". Press enter to draw a random card.")
            random_drawn_card = random.choice(sorted_deck)
            print("Your card: " + str(random_drawn_card))
            sorted_deck.remove(random_drawn_card)
            if random_drawn_card == "Ace♣" or random_drawn_card == "Ace♥" or random_drawn_card == "Ace♦" or random_drawn_card == "Ace♠" or random_drawn_card == "Jack♣" or random_drawn_card == "Jack♥" or random_drawn_card == "Jack♦" or random_drawn_card == "Jack♠":
                user_turn_score = 0
                print("You drew an Ace or a Jack. You will not gain any points this turn.")
                type = "computer"
            else:
                value = random_drawn_card.rank
                user_turn_score = user_turn_score + value
                print("Your points this round: " + str(user_turn_score))
                turn_type = input("Do you want to continue your turn? (Y/N) ")
                if turn_type == "Y":
                    type = "user"
                else:
                    type = "computer"
                    user_score = user_score + user_turn_score
                    print("Your total score: " + user_score)
            print()
            print("***************************************************************")
            print()
        
        else:
            computer_turn_score = 0
            print("It is the computer's turn. Drawing a random card.")
            random_drawn_card = random.choice(sorted_deck)
            print("Computer's Card: " + str(random_drawn_card))
            sorted_deck.remove(random_drawn_card)
            if random_drawn_card == "Ace♣" or random_drawn_card == "Ace♥" or random_drawn_card == "Ace♦" or random_drawn_card == "Ace♠" or random_drawn_card == "Jack♣" or random_drawn_card == "Jack♥" or random_drawn_card == "Jack♦" or random_drawn_card == "Jack♠":
                computer_turn_score = 0
                print("The computer drew an Ace or a Jack. It will not gain any points this turn.")
                type = "computer"
            else:
                value = random_drawn_card.rank
                computer_turn_score = computer_turn_score + value
                print("Computer's points this round: " + str(computer_turn_score))
                computer_turn = random.randint(1,2)
                if computer_turn == 1:
                    type = "computer"
                    print("The computer will take another turn.")
                else:
                    type = "user"
                    computer_score = computer_score + computer_turn_score
                    print("The computer will not take another turn.")
                    print("Computer's total score: " + computer_score)
            print()
            print("***************************************************************")
            print()

user = game_turn(type)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: `global user_score, etc.` is inside the `while` which already tries to access the variable. Move the `global` line to the function-level

Comment: Thanks, my code works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is you are using the variable user_score before the statement `global user_score`.

If you want to use those global variable you should move the `global ...` statement at the beginning of the function (move it up one line).

Comment: Thanks, my code works now!